# Problems with appending screenshot to the Testng report

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am facing problems in getting the screenshots appear in the test report.

Below is the code which I am using to capture screenshots and append it to the report

```
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult tr) {
        Object currentClass = tr.getInstance();
        WebDriver driver = ((TestBase) currentClass).getDriver();
        logger.debug("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ");
        logger.debug("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Fail ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ " + tr.getName());
        logger.debug("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ");
        /* Capturing screen shot */

        Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(tr);

        logger.debug("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Capturing Screen");
        String imageFile;
        Date d = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_YYYY_HH_mm_ss");
        String date = df.format(d);
        Path screenShotPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"), new String[]{"target", "surefire-reports", "Screenshots"});
//        imageFile = screenShotPath + System.getProperty("file.separator") + tr.getName() + "_" + date + ".png";
        String fileName = System.getProperty("file.separator") + tr.getName() + "_" + date + ".png";
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(imageFile));
            Reporter.setEscapeHtml(false);
            Reporter.log("<a href=\"./Screenshots"+fileName+"\" height='100' width='100'>Screenshot</a>");
            Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(null);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.debug(e, new RuntimeException());
        }
    }
```

The screen are being captured. It's even getting appended in the report as shown below:

```html
        <div panel-name="reporter-Life_Made_Easy" class="panel">
          <div class="main-panel-header rounded-window-top">
            <span class="header-content">Reporter output for Life Made Easy</span>
          </div> <!-- main-panel-header rounded-window-top -->
          <div class="main-panel-content rounded-window-bottom">
            <div class="reporter-method-div">
              <span class="reporter-method-name">chkLoginWithInvalidCred</span>
              <div class="reporter-method-output-div">
                <span class="reporter-method-output"><a href="./Screenshots/chkLoginWithInvalidCred_13_06_2016_14_17_16.png" height='100' width='100'>Screenshot</a></span>
              </div> <!-- reporter-method-output-div -->
            </div> <!-- reporter-method-div -->
            <div class="reporter-method-div">
              <span class="reporter-method-name">chkLoginWithValidCred</span>
              <div class="reporter-method-output-div">
                <span class="reporter-method-output"><a href="./Screenshots/chkLoginWithValidCred_13_06_2016_14_16_45.png" height='100' width='100'>Screenshot</a></span>
              </div> <!-- reporter-method-output-div -->
            </div> <!-- reporter-method-div -->
          </div> <!-- main-panel-content rounded-window-bottom -->
        </div> <!-- panel -->
```

When I open the report, I don't see the image. But when open the source of the page and click on the img src, the file opens.

What am i doing wrong? Why is the image not shown in the report.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sorry folks, The screenshots are indeed appearing but in the reporter output. I was assuming it will come inline.

Well is there any way that we can make come inline?

Comment: You should add absolute path instead of relative path

Comment: @Sadik Relative path is working for me. May I know the reason as to why you suggesting me to have absolute path?

Comment: is above working for you ?

Comment: Yes Sadik. It is working.